# Grunt app deployed on Heroku ... and what's next ?... my app doesn't start

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntfile

I have a basic node app with gruntfile and I had some pains to make the deploy. So I did a new grunt task, did some changes. 
The deploy then is fine.

But now when I go to my app. I have a blank page. 
It doesn't load the appConfig.app dir.

I probably miss something big I couldn't figure out. I thought grunt connect would do the wire but it seems server.js is waiting something.

NB : I think I don't need Express here.

Below are different files :

- gruntfile.js
- server.js
- package.js

*Gruntfile.js*

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
require('time-grunt')(grunt);
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');

// Configurable paths for the application
var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

//Environment vars
var envConfig = {
    dev: {
        //baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
        loginUrl: 'http://demo.lvh.me:9000',
        uploadUrl: 'anuploadurl/upload'
    },
    prod: {
        baseUrl: 'http://aprodurl',
        loginUrl: 'an herokuapp url'
    }
};


// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    appConf: appConfig,

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= appConf.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                    '!<%= appConf.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }],
            options: {
                force: true //since dist directory is outside, we must use force flag.
            }
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },

    //server settings
    ngconstant: {
        // Options for all targets
        options: {
            space: '  ',
            wrap: '\'use strict\';\n\n {%= __ngModule %}',
            name: 'config'
        },
        // Environment targets
        development: {
            options: {
                dest: 'app/config.js'
            },
            constants: envConfig.dev
        },
        production: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%= appConf.app %>/config.js'
            },
            constants: envConfig.prod
        }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
        app: {
            src: ['<%= appConf.app %>/index.html'],
            ignorePath: /\.\.\//,
            'options': {
                'overrides': {
                    'semantic-ui': {
                        'main': ['dist/semantic.css', 'dist/semantic.js']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= appConf.app %>/*',
                dest: '<%= appConf.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '{,*/}*.html',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                    'fonts/*'
                ]
            }, {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= appConf.app %>/images',
                dest: '<%= appConf.dist %>/images',
                src: ['generated/*']
            }, { // not in use
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
                src: 'fonts/*',
                dest: '<%= appConf.dist %>'
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= appConf.app %>/*',
                    dest: '<%= appConf.dist %>/styles',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css'
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'copy:styles',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= appConf.app %>/*',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '<%= appConf.dist %>/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            hostname: '0.0.0.0',
            livereload: 35729
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect().use(
                            '/bower_components',
                            connect.static('./bower_components')
                        ),
                        connect.static(appConfig.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        rewriteRulesSnippet,
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect.static('test'),
                        connect().use(
                            '/bower_components',
                            connect.static('./bower_components')
                        ),
                        connect.static(appConfig.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                port:process.env.PORT,
                open: true,
                base: '<%= appConf.app %>'
            }
        }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: {
            src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                'server.js',
                '<%= appConf.app %>/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        }
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['wiredep']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= appConf.app %>/{,**/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            }
        },
        css: {
            files: ['<%= appConf.app %>/styles/{,**/}*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass'],
            options: {
                livereload: true,
            },
        },
        styles: {
            files: [
                '<%= appConf.app %>/styles/{,**/}*.css',
                '<%= appConf.app %>/../templating/css/style.css'
            ],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= appConf.app %>/{,**/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,**/}*.css',
                '<%= appConf.app %>/images/{,**/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
    },

    sass: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded'
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= appConf.app %>/styles',
                    src: ['*.scss'],
                    ext: '.css',
                    dest: '<%= appConf.dist %>/styles'
                }
            ]
        }
    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

// Build the development application
grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function () {

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'ngconstant:development',
        'wiredep',
        'sass',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

 // Build the production application
grunt.registerTask('build', 'Compile app on production settings', function () {

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'ngconstant:production',
        'wiredep',
        'sass',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:dist'
    ]);
});

};
```

*server.js*

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    });
    //res.end('app/index.html');

}).listen(port);
console.log('Server running at port '+port);
```

*package.json*

```
{
"private": true,
"engines": {
  "node": "4.2.2"
},
 "scripts": {
  "postinstall": "bower install && grunt build",
  "start": "node server.js"
 },
 "dependencies": { all the dependancies .... }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Procfile that specifies a web process? Did you scale up the web dyno to > 0?

Comment: @M00B I don't need a Procfile in this config. Also no needs about the dyno upscale. I found the bug in my answer below.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! Sorry I wasn't more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a huge and harsh debugging but I finally found out.

It was coming from multiple mistakes and bugs I had :

1. the node server.js is useless
2. I invstigated on the grunt connect method and created a production setup
3. I splitted the grunt serve into a grunt build task and a webconnect task
4. Then updated package.json file

Very important for heroku : in Gruntfile.js on the connect object :

```
 dist: {
        options: {
            port:process.env.PORT, #<=== need to have a dynamic port env for Heroku deployment
            open: true,
            base: '<%= appConf.dist %>'
        }
    }
```

here are the grunt tasks added :

```
// Build the production application
grunt.registerTask('build', 'Compile on dist folder', function () {

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:dist',
        'ngconstant:production',
        'wiredep',
        'sass',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer:dist'
    ]);
});

// Build the production application
grunt.registerTask('webconnect', 'connect web server', function () {

    grunt.task.run([
        'connect:dist'
    ]);
});
```

then on package.json :

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "bower install && grunt build",
  "start": "grunt webconnect"
}
```